# More eclipse insanity. Changing layout file turns TextViews into LinearLayouts

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Just made a change to my layout.xml  Everything compiles and then I got a weird error back saying can't cast a TextView to ImageView.  Another change and I got a weird error saying cannot cast THE SAME TextView to a LinearLayout???  It turns out although everything may compile fine, sometimes if you don't do a clean project your TextView widget might just be pointing to a RelativeLayout!!!  Does anyone know why?

Comment: Without related code posted, it is hard to guess what the problem can be. I would first suggest a `clean` and `rebuild` of the project, if that doesn't fix the problem, go and double check your layout files and the Java code that use those layout files.

Comment: Did you just repeat my question? Have you heard that before?

Comment: Maybe, but that's how I fix it when encountering the problem. Also, you may want to turn on `Build Automatically`.

Comment: ok. I'll check if i have build auto on.  But other changes outside layout seem to be picked up.

Comment: Yeah I think Build Auto was turned off. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's why:

You might have seen the file `R.java` in the `gen` folder.

Open that file up.

It contains memory addresses and identifiers for all the (R)esources.

When you change your layout files, these memory addresses become outdated and point to the wrong view element.  A clean/build will delete the R.java file and recreate it, and is a necessary step after changing views.

Comment: Where is it documented that a clean is required after changing a layout file?

Comment: hmm no clue, maybe in the R documentation?  And not after every change, I misspoke-- I've only noticed when I change `id`s or move already existing elements around-- changing `attributes` (like width/height/textSize/etc. except for `id`) doesn't require a clean/build.

Comment: Ok. In my case I moved portions of the layout around. But did not change any properties at all.

Comment: yeah, changing the order will do it