# More Eclipse ADT Insanity! Logcat become completely disconnected

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

For no known reason (to me).  The logcat just stops running.  I've tried adb kill-server adb start-server etc, and nothing works except closing eclipse and restarting it.  This is not efficient at all. And its a waste of time.  Does anyone know how to prevent losing logcat data feed, and or how to quickly restore it? And this is about the 100th time at least that this has happened to me. I really cannot see this happening in xCode. Not in this way.  I mean where on earth is the click to reconnect?

Comment: Missed the other parts of this great "eclipse insanity" series? Have a look at [Wrong JDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357619/more-eclipse-insanity-wrong-jdk-is-set-on-imported-projects), [layout files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310588/more-eclipse-insanity-changing-layout-file-turns-textviews-into-linearlayouts) or [another logcat entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047494/more-eclipse-insanity-searching-on-logcat-only-returns-one-line-where-item-occu). -1 & close vote as not constructive per usual. Take your rants to somewhere else.

Comment: And look how many agree with you alextsc! not very impressive. I doubt if xCode developers would muck around with these types of issues. In the meantime, we need to share solutions to these common frustrations.

Comment: Can you give any more information on what's happening?

Comment: have you tried (re)opening the DDMS (use Window->Open Perspective->DDMS) and then (re)selecting the device? That has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have never bumped into this issue before. It did happen to me a few times when the logcat was completely empty but I later found out that I needed to point to the correct device in DDMS for logcat to know where to get its data from.

I don't think this is your issue though, because you were saying that logcat was "losing data feed". It sounds like logcat stops working half-way.